# Command line argument shows up as an empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to pass in an argument to my script but for some reason if I specify `-t` for my time value, it shows up in the script as an empty string. If I specify `--time`, I get the correct value. Why?

```
import sys, getopt, time


def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    sleeptime = 6

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("No arguments supplied")
        print('Usage: test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -t <1-24>')
        sys.exit()

    try:
        opts, arg = getopt.getopt(argv, "i:o:t", ["ifile=", "ofile=", "time="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('Incorrect options.')
        print('Usage: test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -t <1-24>')
        sys.exit()

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-t", "--time"):
            print("time = ", arg)
            sleeptime = int(arg)
        else:
            print("Unknown arg")
            sys.exit()

    print(sleeptime)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I pretty much ripped the code from here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: Why don't you just use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)? That's literally what [the `getopt` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html) suggest.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: ...I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, i think you forgot the trailing colon for the `t` option (since `t` requires an argument), try changing it to `"i:o:t:"`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt.

The whole line should look like this:

```
opts, arg = getopt.getopt(argv, "i:o:t:", ["ifile=", "ofile=", "time="])
```

In general i agree with the comments above though, i would recommend to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html for command line argument parsing :).

Answer (score 2):

In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt):

> *shortopts* is the string of option letters that the script wants to recognize, with options that require an argument followed by a colon

You missed the colon on the `t`.  Modify like this, and it works:

```
opts, arg = getopt.getopt(argv, "i:o:t:", ["ifile=", "ofile=", "time="])
```